# Cleaner way to do this in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement

I have some code in one of my views like this. I feel that it has too many if else conditions. All it does is checking for the ActiveRecord Object's status and setting the image. Is there a better way to do the following in Rails?

```
<td class="notification_msg">
  <% if notification.status == NOTIFICATION_STATUS.index("Failure") %>
     <img src="images/failure.png" style="vertical-align: middle"/>
  <% elsif notification.status == NOTIFICATION_STATUS.index("Success") %>
     <img src="images/success.png" style="vertical-align: middle"/>
  <% elsif notification.status == NOTIFICATION_STATUS.index("Warning") %>
     <img src="images/warning.gif" style="vertical-align: middle"/>
  <% else %>
     <img src="images/unknown.gif" style="vertical-align: middle"/>
  <% end %>
  <%= notification.message %> <%= cta_links_for(notification) -%>
</td>
```

Thanks

Comment: why do you display success.png on failure?

Comment: @marcgg: My bad.. it was a typo.. corrected it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd pull the logic into a helper. Your erb:

```
<td class="notification_msg"> 
  <%= notification_image(notification.status) %> 
  <%= notification.message %> <%= cta_links_for(notification) -%> 
</td>
```

Then in your view helper:

```
def notification_image(status)
  name = NOTIFICATION_STATUS[status].downcase
  return image_tag "#{name}.png"
end
```

And of course, no inline styles. So put `.notification_msg img{vertical-align:middle;}` in your css file.

Answer (score 4):

You can change

```
 <img src="images/success.png" style="vertical-align: middle"/>
```

In

```
= image_tag "success.png
```

Then use CSS:

```
.notification_msg img{vertical-align:middle;}
```

I'm confused by why you display success.png on failure, I'll add more info to my answer once you explained that :)

---

From what I understand here what I would have done:

erb:

```
<td class="notification_msg">
  <%= image_tag "#{notification.status}.png" %>
  <%= notification.message %> <%= cta_links_for(notification) -%>
</td>
```

css:

```
.notification_msg img{vertical-align:middle;}
```

It's not error-proof but I hope it'll give you an idea

Comment: Thanks for your instant response. If we put `#{notifiction.status}.png` directly, wouldnt that increase the coupling between the image files and the view ?